# What is the data type for images in java

Tags: java, image

The below code is for get and set the attributes for string, like this what is the data type to define the image, profile_picture is the variable for image. I'm going to store the image in DB.

```
private Long id;
public String first_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setfirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name =first_name;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What type is the best to manage binary data in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606623/what-type-is-the-best-to-manage-binary-data-in-java)

Comment: @bot I **don't** think so...

Comment: use byte[] to store images in form of blob in database if you use.

Comment: @NabeelOmer Don't forget that the results need to be stored into a database

Comment: @bot **Sorry**, just realized....

Comment: in DB bytea is a data type for images, But when define in java, i don't know what is the data type

Answer (score 6):

If you do **no image processing in java**, you could store the bytes, `byte[]` or on database level (SQL BLOB, binary large object), a `SerialBlob` (implements the interface `Blob`).

Maintaining the images as files with only the paths in the database, also has its merits. In a mixed approach you can read/write a file to a blob database column, just using Input/OutputStream which saves memory.

Answer (score 4):

You may use either to represent a 2D image-

1. [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)
2. [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)

**Edit:** For saving image in database you may convert `BufferredImage` to `byte[]` (and then save it as `BLOB` in DB) using the following code snippet -

```
try{

    BufferedImage originalImage = 
                              ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/image/imag.jpg"));

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write( originalImage, "jpg", baos );
    baos.flush();
    byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

    //save imageInByte as blob in database
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
       baos.close();
       //close database connection
    }
```

Comment: BufferedImage is a direct subclass of Image.

Answer (score 4):

```
URL iconURL = new URL("");
// iconURL is null when not found
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
Image i = icon.getImage();
```

`Image i;` is the variable that stores the the image, You can use it from there.

Cheers.

**Edit:** I suggest that instead of saving the whole image in the database, just save the *path to the image....*

Comment: How would you store this in the database?

Comment: @bot The question is _"What is the data type for images in java"_ and I have  shown in my answer that this is a data type.

Comment: `I'm going to store the image in DB`. That is also the part of the quesiton.

Comment: @bot That is also true but the most basic kind of Image data type, in Java is `Image`. And I would suggest this person not to save the whole image in the database but only the path to the image...

Answer (score 1):

```
        File f = new File("D:/New Doc_1.jpg");
        int length = (int)f.length(); 
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        pstmt.setBinaryStream(3, fis,length);
        int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```